# How do I insert a background image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Am still new to coding, can someone please explain or or give an example on how I can insert a background image using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

**// Code to set background image for the html body**

```
 document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img.png')";
```

**// Code to set background image for a div**

```
document.getElementById(DivId).style.backgroundImage = "url('img.png')";
```